# Crystal Field Splitting Energy - Tetrachlorocuprate and Tetrachlorocobaltate

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals, ligand-field-theory

I'm a high schooler from India and it's my first time on this stack exchange. I was wondering why the crystal field splitting energy of tetrachlorocuprate differs so much from tetrachlorocobaltate.

[image: Absorbance Spectrum]Peaks at  ~410 nm
253.457 kJ/mol for the copper(II) complex

[image: Absorbance Spectrum]

Peaks at ~690nm at 175.5 kJ/mol for the cobalt (II) complex.
The general trend amongst octahedral cobalt and copper complexes is that cobalt experiences a greater crystal field splitting energy. But when it comes to tetrahedrals, how do I explain this? I have considered the Jahn-Teller distortion but I suppose there must be more to it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think it can be attributed to the fact that copper (II) forms a square planar geometry usually since it would be d8.

Comment: What am I seeing here? What are these images? How do you come from a wavelength to a splitting energy?

Comment: E = hv --> E = hc/λ where λ is the wavelength of maximum absorbance. The images I've attached are the absorption spectra of the relevant complexes. The wavelength at which the absorption is the maximum is λmax.